# Recording phone call in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

**Is there any api for call recording in iOS while the conversation is going on?**

The requirement is that i want to record the desired part of the call and store locally in the device such that i  an move it to my storage disks later.

Does there any apps exist with this capability...such that we can record during the call is going on??

Know about the legal issues and gone through other questions in stack.Want to know any further improvements by iOS5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such API in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

No sir.. there is no such thing.(IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

One word answer. "**No**"...!! Not in the current SDK.